# What is the difference between Docker Desktop and Rancher Desktop?

Tags: docker, rancher

The difference between Docker Desktop and Rancher Desktop, especially to what extend Rancher Desktop uses docker features, plugins etc, is not trivial.

E.g. the [Docker Scout CLI plugin](https://docs.docker.com/scout/install/) comes pre-installed with Docker Desktop. But for Rancher Desktop it must be manually installed.

Does Rancher Desktop uses the same Docker Engine: Docker Server, Docker CLI and Rest API as Docker Desktop?
Why I can not use some [docker commands](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/), such as `docker init`,`docker debug` with Rancher Desktop? (It is not available as plugin.)

P.S. General differences of Docker Desktop and Rancher Desktop explained in this [article](https://codeengineered.com/blog/2022/docker-desktop-vs-rancher-desktop/) are clear.